# Spring boot not able to resolve OS environment variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I deployed spring boot service to AWS and application.properties has refers to one of the OS environment variable which is being set as part of deployment process. It seems like Spring Boot fails to resolve the OS environment variable when booting up.

If I echo the variable it seems to be set correctly -

```
ubuntu@ip-10-227-74-206:~$ echo $EC2_INSTANCE_ID
i-de8c136d
```

application.properties file refers to that variable as below -

```
service.hostId=aws-${EC2_INSTANCE_ID}
```

I see below error when booting up the application -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.foo.services.registration.config; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'EC2_INSTANCE_ID' in string value "${EC2_INSTANCE_ID}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Do I need to add any prefix like "sys:" when referring in application.properties file?

Comment: Are you sure the variable is globally available and not only for the local shell?

Comment: Yes, variable is defined in /etc/environment file and it is sourced via /etc/bash.bashrc. Logging into host and than echo-ing works. May be I am totally wrong path but some reading around on forums suggested that init script may not be using interactive login shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending lot of time, it feels like something to do with init script in spring-boot. I found some workaround it not ideal but got things done -

Source environment variable in the init conf file.

> source /etc/environment

This makes environment variable able to parent process which starts spring boot application. Now pass all environment variable as JAVA_OPTS in conf file

JAVA_OPTS="-Denv.variable=${var.foo}"

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Value` annotation to injected OS var in your beans.

Ref: [Spring Boot documentation about Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)